# How to send email with delay?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, email

I have ASP.NET MVC application and I need to send email in "X" minutes(for each user time is different) to user after he leaves the page.
How can I do it?

Comment: hmm. It's not going to be straight forward. You could just implement a cron job, have a url send the email and call this url X minutes from you server. This will only work if you have this kinda control on your server. Or, if you have decent traffic, on every new request you check previous records to see if those mins have passed and then you send your mail.

Comment: This should be delegated to a service of some kind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Http is stateless and the time response is sent execution of page is finished. You need an application that will be sending mail even when website is not accessed by some body for a significant time interval. You can put the mails that need to be send after an interval of time in the database. Another application could be a Windows service that will pool the database after fixed interval of time let's say 30 seconds and send the mails which have reached the send time.

Comment: I agree.  If these emails are important, then putting them into a DB table is important, so that your service that reads the table and sends emails can do so in a transaction.  If you didn't use a DB, and queued them into some sort of service, then they only exist in memory until the time elapses and they are sent.  Thus if the service goes down, the queued email will be lost.  It depends on how important these emails are.  It also would perform better than having the service have to track the emails.  Instead it just polls the table and sees which ones SendAtTime <= DateTime.Now (or UTC?)

Answer (score 1):

The solution I would choose depends on the needed scale and reliability of the system you're building.

If it's a low scale (i.e. 1 server with not too many users at the same time), non mission-critical system (i.e. it's OK if from time to time some emails are not actually sent, for example if your server crashes), then the solution can be as simple as managing a queue in memory with a thread that would wake periodically to send emails to the users that recently left the page.

If you need to build something that would be very reliable and potentially have to send a very large number of emails in a short time, and if your system has to scale to a lot of machines, then you would want to build a solution based on a queue in some storage, where as many machines as needed would pick items and handle them. An API such as Windows Azure Queue Service can be a good fit for this if you need a really high scale and reliability.